# Blank page when deploying a Nextjs repository

Tags: reactjs, next.js, deployment, netlify

deploy a repo in netlify successfuly but it shows a blank page instead of my site:
This is my [repo](https://github.com/ssadeghh/portfolio)
and this is [netlify site](https://inspiring-fox-150587.netlify.app/)

this is my netlify building setting:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the `index.html` in the public folder. Netlify sees this as the root of the page instead of the `.next` folder's `index.html`

[Delete this](https://github.com/ssadeghh/portfolio/blob/main/public/index.html) and redeploy!

Cool site btw!